# Selecting h2 element via XPath

Tags: python, selenium

I would need to access this element via XPath:

```
<section class="section">
  <div class="help-info">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="tile tile--bottom">
        <h2 class="force--h4">Sorry, xxx could not be found or reached (error code 404) </h2> ==$0
```

I tried with

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h2[text()='Sorry, xxx could not be found or reached (error code 404)']")))
```

But actually it does not look at the right element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried the below `CSS_SELECTOR` :

```
section.section div.container h2
```

with explicit waits like :

```
h_ele = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "section.section div.container h2")))
print(h_ele.text)
```

Comment: Hi cruisepandey and Fazlul, I have opened a new question since I am getting an TimeoutException error, probably due to a change of element located. In case you might want to have a look and help me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69421166/timeoutexception-due-to-a-change-of-tags#

Comment: @LdM :  I have given you a solution over there, Please have a look.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
//h2[@class="force--h4"]
```