# TimeoutException due to a change of tags?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am having some problems with TimeoutException.

My code has always run fine in the past days but today something has changed since I am getting the TimeoutException error message. More likely is due to a locator change on the website.

My code is structured as follows:

```
# Initialise Chrome parameters
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

# Open Chrome
driver=webdriver.Chrome(path,chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.maximize_window()
    
response=driver.get(my_web)


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
time.sleep(randrange(5))
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1000)")


message = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"section.section div.container h2"))).text
        t_score = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Trustscore']/../following-sibling::div/descendant::div[@class='icon']"))).text
```

I have tried to change the time wait even to 60sec, but nothing has changed since I a getting the same error.

The error is returned due to the following: `section.section div.container h2.` I am interested in Trustscore.

[URL here](http://scamadviser.com/check-website/stackoverflow.com)

Comment: the website for reference is: https://www.scamadviser.com/check-website/stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your paths are incorrect. I assume the html has changed. You could use:

```
message = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".trustdata-alert strong:last-child"))).text
t_score = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".trustscore-rating"))).text
```

However,

1. You need a better wait condition as the rating can be slow to fully update leading to printing an incorrect value.
2. There are anti-bot cloudflare measures meaning scraping is likely against T&C and you will get a captcha at some point and possibly a ban.

Comment: Did you try that xpath?

Comment: I tried it again after restarting the notebook and it worked. Thanks QHarr

Comment: trying with this other website https://www.scamadviser.com/check-website/limetorrent.ws , I get the same error. Ido you spot any difference in elements using this website?

Comment: Change the first selector to `.trustdata-alert strong:last-child`   - I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what HTML the website had earlier, But I do this `outer HTML` for `Trustscore`.

```
<div class="trustscore-rating"><span style="color: rgb(0, 177, 106);">100</span> / 100</div>
```

I have looked upon the HTMLDOM and we have a a unique entry for this div.

Please use this `css_selector` :

```
div.trustscore-rating
```

**Code 1 :**

```
message = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.trustscore-rating"))).text
```

**or**

```
message = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.trustscore-rating"))).get_attribute('innerText')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, cruisepandey. I marked QHarr's answer because I. needed to use both message and t_score paths to make the code working. Thank you for your help